# Is it possible to start another engine of Mil Mi 8 with one engine started and APU off?

Tags: helicopter, russia

In the 737NG, it is possible to start the other engine without APU if one engine is already started, by routing air from the started engine to the other one.

Is this possible in the Mil Mi 8 helicopter?

Answer (score 4):

From that I see in the quite detailed description of the helicopter systems in [Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8-8#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), looks like both engines have independent electric starters (starters-generators) so could be started independently.

There is no mentioning of APU in the description of all systems. They say power plant consists of the two engines. However as mentioned in comments, the helicopter does have the control panel for starting the "[Турбоагрегат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82)". It is generally a name for the device that combines turbine engine and electricity generator. APU is called "[Вспомогательная силовая установка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) (ВСУ)" in Russian.

Comment: Mi-8 definitely has an APU.  You can see the relevant controls above the center of the windscreen, second panel from the bottom.  https://www.airliners.net/photo/Poland-Navy/Mil-Mi-17/2146005/L

Comment: While I can see a down vote for the incorrect assertion that the Mi8 doesn't have an APU, I'd say this deserves an up vote for answering the question by noting that it has electric starters and doesn't require the APU for either main engine start. Including the relevant Wiki quote (and a translation to English, even if it's a machine translation) is the expectation (links die and sources can get edited) would be worth another up vote (if only I had a 2nd to give).

Comment: I added comment about the existence of the ""Турбоагрегат".

Comment: From the linked article:  "Вертолёты поздних серий (Ми-8МТ, Ми-17 и др.) значительно модернизированы. Двигатели заменены на более мощные (взлётная мощность — 2200 л. с.) ТВ3-117 с 12-ступенчатым компрессором и воздушным запуском, для подачи воздуха к воздушным стартёрам двигателей установлена ВСУ АИ-9В."  The newer Mi-8s DO have APUs, and that's what the questioner is asking about.  This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: This sort of answers my question. Thank you, comrade!